# Declare an iterator for an rdd in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My requirement is to iterate over an rdd with 2 iterators. My operation depends on 2 different rows.
Ex. (1, Add, 10),(1,Add, 20),(1, Sub, 15)
In this case, my first iterator is at the 1st element, but my operation starts at the first instance where 'Sub' is found. When Sub is found, I need to subtract from the tuple that contains Add and then move on to the next.

Looking for some direction to do this in Spark using Scala.

Edit:

this is my rdd:

```
val testData= ((1, Add, 10),(1,Add, 20),(1, Sub, 15))
```

The 1st element of the 1st tuple is the key based on which I need to perform an operation. I start my operation at the 1st instance of the tuple containing 'Sub'. Subtract the 3rd element of the tuple from the corresponding 3rd element of the 1st tuple that contains 'Add'. If I have more to subtract than that is available, I move to the next tuple containing 'Add' to subtract the remaining.

I've simplified my use case and presented it here:

```
(1, Add, 10), <- 1st iterator
(1, Add, 20),
(1, Sub, 15)  <- 2nd iterator
```

After 1st iteration

```
(1, Add, 0), 
(1, Add, 20), <- 1st iterator
(1, Sub, 5)  <- 2nd iterator
```

After 2nd  iteration

```
(1, Add, 0), 
(1, Add, 15), <- 1st iterator
(1, Sub, 0)  <- 2nd iterator
```

I cannot do this by just adding all the elements that contain 'Add' and do the same with 'Sub' because each is associated with a date that I need to take care of, in the actual use case.

Comment: _My requirement is to iterate over an rdd with 2 iterators._  - then you're decided to use a wrong tool. There is a good chance it is the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) but unless you spend some time to write a question which exactly describes your problem, inputs and expected output we won't be able to help you.

Comment: @zero323, I've added some explanation, hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem that you want to solve instead of how you are trying to solve it?